# A wstring wrapper to std::runtime_error exception?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, wstring

Supposing I have these functions defined somewhere:

```
std::string ws_to_s(const wchar_t*);
std::string ws_to_s(const std::wstring&);
std::wstring s_to_ws(const char*);
```

I wrote this class:

```
class runtime_error_w : public std::runtime_error {
public:
  runtime_error_w() = default;

  runtime_error_w(const wchar_t* what_arg)
    : runtime_error(ws_to_s(what_arg)) { }

  runtime_error_w(const std::wstring& what_arg)
    : runtime_error(ws_to_s(what_arg)) { }

  virtual const std::wstring what_w() const noexcept {
    return ws_to_s(what());
  }
};
```

So far this worked for me, but is there any problem with this approach?

Notice that `what_w()` returns a `std::string` object, not a `const char*`.

Comment: One potential problem is that constructing the `wstring` might throw a `bad_alloc`, which would be a problem if it happens during the handling of the original exception.

Comment: Correct, but [should I worry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9456758/6923555) about a `bad_alloc`?

Comment: Yes, you should worry about bad_alloc. Not handling an exception and letting it escape to generic uncaught exception handler, while letting RAII and stack unwinding ensure data coherence is one thing. Making code call std::terminate and potentially losing data is another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments below the question, I agree that it's a **bad idea** to use this class, because of a potential `bad_alloc` raising when constructing `wstring`.