# C++ program using more memory than available on the system?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I've written the following memory hogging program:

```
int main() {
    while(1) {
        auto* blah = new char[1024 * 1024 * 1024]{};
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which, as far I can tell, reserves a whole GB of memory on every iteration on the loop. I was expecting this to crash almost immediately. But it somehow runs until I stop it.
Inspecting my system I discovered that my little program is taking up more memory than available on my machine, how is this possible? what's going on here?

[image]

Comment: Presumably it's immediately getting swapped to [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and then, because you never read from any of the giant matrices you create, never swapped back.

Comment: This was my guess, so the OS is supposedly moving memory from RAM to the disk giving the illusion of larger RAM memory, did not know the name for it though!

Comment: (a) virtual memory; (b) virtual address space; (c) pages not being committed until written too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern operating systems can be clever about memory allocation and not actually allocate anything until you use the memory you tried to allocate. On such systems `malloc` and `new` don't fail when you allocate, but the whole program goes down when you try to use the memory OS told you it allocated even though it physically can't. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9456758/10147399) for more on that.

Answer (score 0):

Add `blah[1024 * 1024 * 1024 - 1] = 127;` after line with `new`. Probably there is optimisation for unused block of memory. Have you tried to see (printf) the addresses allocated for `blah`?

Comment: While true, this feels more like a comment. It doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Tried adding the assignment, same results. The program runs indefinitely.

Comment: @ FRR Won't necessarily cause a detectable error for a long time. Accessing only one element of a huge array may result in only the [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)) containing the one element actually being allocated to the program. And then this page will go unused and be swapped out, freeing up the memory for a future allocation..

Comment: Then the assignment can be replaced with `memset( blah, 0, 1024 * 1024 * 1024 );`