# exception on std string using move constructor

Tags: c++

Is `noexcept` good  in the code below ? according to [cppreference](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) the string move constructor never throw exception and if i undrestant well `rvalue + lvalue = rvalue`

```
void foo(const std::string& p_str) noexcept{
   std::string l_str {p_str + "FOO"};
}
```

Comment: Probably not, string can do dynamic memory allocation so you could in theory expect std::bad_alloc. (p_str + "FOO" will not only be a move constructor call, but will create a new temporary std::string)

Comment: that is the case of other constructors not the move one i think

Comment: @casaDePapel It is, indeed, though in the context of the question (*'is noexcept good **in the code below**'*) the answer still remains *'no'*...

Comment: @Aconcagua my static code analyser : Polyspace is not agree, it doen't accept noexcept here! maybe bugg on it ?

Comment: It does *not* accept `noexcept`? But that's what we're saying, too: *'It is **not** good'*. The move constructor doesn't throw, indeed, but `operator+` creates a totally new `std::string` (as Pepijn explained already) – a temporary – and *that one* might throw on construction. What is passed to the move constructor is *not* p_str, but this temporary instead. If an exception is thrown, then even *before* the move constructor gets called.

Comment: "https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B" Is NOT noexcept, so your analyser is correct

Comment: Actually the move constructor should not get called at all here (but still is required to exist!) due to copy elision/return value optimisation...

Comment: @Aconcagua, @Pepijn Kramer
  you are right, thank you, the pb is with the ``` operator+ ```

Comment: @Aconcagua you mean that rvalue + lvalue = rvalue is not good ?

Comment: `noexcept` in this piece of code is not good. That's what the entire question is about, isn't it? `noexcept` is mentioned in the sentence right before, isn't it?  You seem to deliberately misinterpret my comments :(

Comment: @Aconcagua (sorry), ok for noexcept i undrestant. it was just about this: (the move constructor should not get called at all here)

Comment: `noexcept` means you intend for the function you've designed to not throw exceptions. As far as I'm concerned, If I had a function to add strings together, I would not be expecting it to throw an error, and should my code reach a point where it does, for instance if it can no longer allocate memory, you're very much screwed. [see more on bad_alloc, I approve highly of the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456728/how-to-deal-with-bad-alloc-in-c). in short, just because you call functions where it may throw, doesn't mean you have to making it's callers `noexcept(false)`

Comment: @Salih MSA noexcept(false) is equivalent to not qualify function i think but for static code analyser is better to put noexpect(false)

Comment: @casaDePapel I agree. It also has the benefit in that all code I write, especially when I know the code will need to be ran and possibly modified by others, it's yet another way of clearly demonstrating intentions.

Comment: @casaDePapel Never mind... OK, then is this new context: `any value + any value = rvalue` – this remains true. However due to return value optimisation and copy elision we can expect that in the final compiled code the string resulting from the call to `operator+` will be constructed *directly* at `l_str`, ommitting the temporary entirely and thus the need for calling the move constructor.

Answer (score 1):

not really, you don't have move here. In fact, you are constructing a new std::string object when doing `+"FOO"`, which means you are doing memory allocation. Which means it can throw.